# SocketTesterARC disconnectedWithError: Called after Connection

Tags: ios, node.js, socket.io

I am using SocketTesterARC for connection to node server. first time when i run code socket get connected and then **didReceiveEvent:** get called. After this process if I called **sendEvent:** server gets disconnected.

```
2015-10-17 11:29:07.067 SocketNew[621:115352] onDisconnect()
2015-10-17 11:29:32.070 SocketNew[621:115352] start/reset timeout
2015-10-17 11:29:32.090 SocketNew[621:115352] event
2015-10-17 11:29:32.091 SocketNew[621:115352] didReceiveEvent >>> data: {
args =     (
    "m_PkgKh7XmcX4B_dDp-2"
);
name = connected;
}

2015-10-17 11:30:07.409 SocketNew[621:115352] send()
2015-10-17 11:30:07.410 SocketNew[621:115352] send() >>> 5:::{"args":["{\"sequence\":\"55547876721444995060\",\"userId\":\"77\",\"socketId\":\"bducg4h5h8fh4bbl92hj\"}"],"name":"checkStatus"}
2015-10-17 11:30:07.415 SocketNew[621:115352] Timed out waiting for heartbeat.
2015-10-17 11:30:07.415 SocketNew[621:115352] onDisconnect()
2015-10-17 11:30:18.272 SocketNew[621:115352] socket.io disconnected. did error occur? Error Domain=SocketIOError Code=-3 "(null)"
```

I am not getting the issue here. I also go through this link [socket.io emit data will disconnect the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420420/socket-io-emit-data-will-disconnect-the-client)

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Is there any Alternative of SocketTesterARC ??

Comment: From server you are disconnected, may be you are not sending correct data so it is disconnecting you.

Comment: In which form I have to send data? Can you elaborate? I am sending in json