# "Cannot read property of undefined" even after hasOwnProperty check

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, undefined

I've been testing a web application that uses node.js and socket.io. Everything is running fine, but out of the many tests in one isolated time I got the following error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'socket' of undefined"
```

This is the line the error was referring to:

```
for(var ID in playersPublic) {
        if(clients.hasOwnProperty(ID)) {
            clients[ID].socket.emit('players', playersPrivate[ID].playersToEmit);
            //The following line is where the error happened:
            clients[ID].socket.emit('food', playersPrivate[ID].foodToEmit);
        }
    }
```

There is absolutely no apparent reason such an error could take place. I cannot cause it to occur again and I do not know what specific circumstances caused it, but I am worried because having crashed the server - even if only once - implies something amiss in the code's logic that could cause more errors or crashes once the server is public. Furthermore, I am puzzled as to how clients[ID] can be undefined even after explicitly checking with hasOwnProperty whether clients[ID] is defined -- and even more puzzling, the error referred to the second line attempting to access clients[ID].socket, therefore on the previous 
line there was no problem accessing it. In what possible scenario could such a thing happen?

Edit: I added the following logs:

```
   if(clients.hasOwnProperty(ID)) {
        if(clients[ID] == null) {
            console.log('NULL BEFORE');
        }
        clients[ID].socket.emit('players', playersPrivate[ID].playersToEmit);
        if(clients[ID] == null) {
            console.log('NULL AFTER');
        }
        clients[ID].socket.emit('food', playersPrivate[ID].foodToEmit);
    }
```

Which resulted in this output in the console:

```
NULL AFTER
G:\ioserver.js:262
                        clients[ID].socket.emit('food', playersPrivate[ID].foodToEmit);
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'socket' of undefined
```

So how the hell could a socket emission cause the object to become null/undefined?

Comment: The property can exist but its value is `undefined`. `let a = {x: undefined}`

Comment: Properties can have the value `undefined`. `var obj = {foo: undefined}; console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty(foo)); obj.foo.bar;`

Comment: What is `clients[ID]` in the first & second line? Can you share the console.log?

Comment: Well *having* the property still means the value could be `undefined`

Comment: FYI, the purpose of `hasOwnProperty()` is not to verify that the property exists -- that's already obvious because `for-in` found the property. This function is used to skip properties that are inherited from the prototype.

Comment: If the value is undefined, then how come the previous line gives no errors? The error just happened again, and it is completely random.

`G:\ioserver.js:256
                        clients[ID].socket.emit('food', playersPrivate[ID].foodToEmit);
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'socket' of undefined`

Comment: log "clients[id]" ... it may the client reference gets deleted while doing the first emit

That way the second one fails as its simply no longer there

Comment: @The_Original JS is single-threaded, how can that happen?

Comment: @Barmar: because its single threaded :)

When someone is listens to the "emit", the handler functions get executed before the execution of the function continues - when having implicit dependancies something like the described error occours

Comment: I added some logs, see question edits

Comment: As @The_Original points out, the problem must be in the code that listens for the `players` message. It's changing the `clients` array.

Comment: How could the code that listens for the message change the clients object? That's impossible - it is executed in the front end. The only way that it could change it would be to emit another message to the server that causes the server to change the array. However, if that was the case, then the message would be registered by the server long after it executes the line of code after the first emission (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Strange -- it does seem to be the case that the object goes null after the first emission. The only place in my code where I delete clients[ID] is upon disconnection. So is it possible that the following chain of events causes the bug:
1. Client is connected; 2. Line checks whether clients[ID] exists 3. First emission occurs 4. Client disconnects (before first emission is finished) which triggers the line in the server that deletes clients[ID] 5. First emission finishes, second emission attempts to start, but clients[ID] is now null.... is this possible?

Comment: If it is not executed while the emit, it would start after your routine has finished  - as js is single threaded async executions have to be delayed.

And it would be some kind of race condition, so the error would only occour from time to time. As it sounds like you can reproduce it frequently, something happens while emitting

Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420420/socket-io-emit-data-will-disconnect-the-client

Comment: Evidently the error is caused exactly by what I described above. See my answer --

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the error was caused by the following chain of events. Note that when a socket disconnects, its corresponding instance in the clients object is deleted. Therefore this is what happens (seldom):

1. User connects and an instance with their ID is created in the clients object
2. Emit function triggers. Server checks whether clients has a key with the user's ID. It does. Server begins the first emission (the line before the error)
3. User disconnects and the instance with their ID in the clients object is deleted.
4. First emission is finished. Server tries to begin second emission, but clients[ID] no longer exists.

Proven by adding three logs - one when user disconnects, one before first emission, one before second emission (all accompanied by the user's ID). Here is the result in the console:

```
emitting players...3pn9-inWwAn_cQaiAAAB
disconnecting user...3pn9-inWwAn_cQaiAAAB
emitting food...3pn9-inWwAn_cQaiAAAB
G:\ioserver.js:267
                        clients[ID].socket.emit('food', playersPrivate[ID].foodToEmit);
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'socket' of undefined
```

Therefore, the simple fix is to once again check whether clients[ID] is null after the first emission.